# Making <li> element 'active' rather than <a> element

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I've got an unordered list using Bootstrap and Ember.js. Each list item is a link to display a new post, and whenever you click on the link, Ember adds the class `active` by default. I'm using Bootstrap `nav-pills` that turn blue when the class is `active`. However, Ember makes the link `active` whereas I'd like it to make the whole `<li>` active.

Here's my template:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    {{#each post in controller}}
        <li class="list-group-item">
            {{#link-to 'post' post}}
                {{post.title}}
            {{/link-to}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

When you click on a link, the `<li>` looks like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
    <a id="ember360" class="ember-view active" href="#/posts/1">
        A great post
    </a>
</li>
```

I know that it would be fairly trivial to add this functionality with jQuery, but is there a way to make the `<li>` active rather than the `<a>` with Ember or Handlebars directly? I tried putting the `{{link-to}}` around the `<li>` and that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Use parent.addClass()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the `link-to` generated tag to `<li>` using `tagName="li"` option. And keep the `<a>` tag to just keep the bootstrap style:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    {{#each post in controller}}        
          {{#link-to 'post' post tagName="li" class="list-group-item" }}
              <a href="#">{{post.title}}</a>
          {{/link-to}}   
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

See this in action http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/YLN5X/

Comment: Great! Simple and effective. I removed the 'list-group-item' class as it looks better, but the solution worked wonderfully.

Comment: Glad to help! I keep the list-group-item class, because your initial code had it too.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. This is significantly easier than messing around with computed properties.

Comment: Simple thought --> this degrades the use of `open in new tab` for the links right

Comment: interesting, I never actually thought to try just setting the tagname and I will keep that in mind. Typically as your app grows however a reference the selected object in a master/detail list will become needed for more than highlighting navigation, so keep my technique for managing selection in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any super easy way, I think the best way would be to extend the LinkView, and register a new helper, link-to-bootstrap, or something along those lines that added the class to the li element instead of the anchor element.

There is a really good project that already does this https://github.com/ember-addons/bootstrap-for-ember

Comment: Interesting project. Are you using this for your projects? I'm curious as to how reliably it works.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in way. The active class binding code is internal to link-to, and involves several not-easy-to-abstract pieces.

The best solution is to have the routes set the selected post in the postsController. This would look like:

```
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('model', model);
      this.controllerFor('posts').set('selection', model);
    },
```

Then you want to open the item controller for posts (PostController unless you set itemController to something different on PostsController) and do something like this:

```
    selection: Ember.computed.alias("parentController.selection"),
    isActive: Ember.computed.equal("model", "parentController.selection")
```

Then in your li:

```
    <li {{bind-attr class="isActive:active :list-group-item"}}>
```

Comment: Is the `setupController` meant to be a method in my postsRoute?